# dart, total available string characters?

Tags: numbers, dart, character

I'm not familiar with character sets and whether languages pick them up from their environments or if they are baked into the language itself, I wanted to make a simple number system in dart that has the largest possible base it can have, like hex has 0-9a-f I would have every single character in some specified ascending order with lower case and upper case having different values to give me the largest possible base to my number system. I want to do this so I can send numbers as strings with as few characters as possible, so my question is, does dart have a standard baked in character set that I can be certain will exist in every environment it runs in?

Comment: Why even bother with character sets in this situation? Couldn't you just use raw byte values instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use every value even if no concrete character is assigned to a code.
This would only be a problem when you try to display the character.

Some codes are control characters with special meaning (like `0x0000`) which you should avoid
more info here: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt.

If you want to transport the result over the internet using text protocols you may be limited to ASCII. In this case I suggest Base64 encoding.

Comment: yeh the point is I want to transfer numbers over http in json strings, and make the number "look" as "short" as possible. Im making the assumption that this will save me data usage over my internet connection.

Comment: As @MarioP wrote, just use binary in this case.

Comment: wouldn't binary produce the longest possible string?

Comment: Absolutely not. You can use every available bit to your liking. Why do you think binary may be longer?

Comment: if I write 16 as a hex its just 'f' as dec its '16' and as binary its '10000' therefore the larger the base the shorter the string representation?

Comment: '15' and '0xf' ('16' == '0x10' hex) is only displayed on the screen (human readable). When used in a context of hexadecimal number '0xf' is internally '1111' (not 10000, 0x10 == 10000). 'f' as a character is internally stored as a byte (01100110). '0x' is only to indicate it's a hexadecimal literal.

Comment: I am writing a specially formatted string to transfer type info across http, if I have an object like `{aNumber: 9879}` it will get serialized to a string `aNumber:n:4:9879` as I use format `propertyName:propertyTypeKey:propertyDataLength:propertyValue` so on the other end my string is deserialized into an object with the same property name, type and value. for a number only example it looks pointless but I allow for any object type to be registered so any type can be converted to or from string representation, and this is the format I use to send that info.

Comment: so as I see it I have to use string representation for my numbers that Im sending in this format.

Comment: I'm not sure how you come to the conclusion that you have to use string then. Have you considered compression? That usually works pretty efficient with strings. This can be activated so that server and browser do that transparently if it is supported by all participants.

Comment: well the serialization produces a large string, which can be compressed, but the individual parts need to be regular string characters, `"aNum:n:4:9879aStr:s:16:a sixteen lengthaDateTime:d:23:2014-02-26 00:00:00.000"` so I'll end up with one big string to send down the http connection, in the previuos example I want to represent the values 4, 16 and 23 as the shortest and safest string representation I can, so I think your final paragraph about base64 is the way to go. after I have the whole string it can be compressed by the server without my knowledge.